# Looking for WPF controls to mimic the ios springboard's behavior

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid with 6 blocks and I want to be able to perform the same actions as in the springboard of ios:
- move blocks
- remove blocks
- group blocks together

I'm looking for something easier to use than a dock control which meets my requirements above.

Comment: As a request for a software tool/library, this is unfortunately off-topic.

Comment: This is off topic here. But still please check out devexpress.com controls for wpf. You'll obviously find what you need.

Comment: Please use DevExpress